# Trying to programaticaly add custom controls to a page in MAUI

Tags: controls, maui

in the parent page i have a colelction view

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Players}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type contentViews:PlayerStubContentView}">
                <SwipeView>
                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <SwipeItems>
                            <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                       Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:PlayersViewModel}}, Path=DeleteCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                       BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                        </SwipeItems>
                    </SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <Grid Padding="0.5">
                        <Frame>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:PlayersViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                                FontSize="24"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </SwipeView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

in the view model for the main page i've got a load method

```
private async void LoadPlayerSave()
{
    var playerModels = await _playerService.GetPlayers();
    foreach(var playerModel in playerModels)
    {
        Players.Add(new PlayerStubContentView() { Name = playerModel.Name, PowerLevel = playerModel.LastPowerLevel.ToString(), Points = playerModel.Points.ToString()});
    }
}
```

the Players property is an observable property

```
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<PlayerStubContentView> players;
```

that the xaml is using as a binding source

the type i've specified is the custom control i've made

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="PodManager.ContentViews.PlayerStubContentView">
<ContentView.ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions=".30*, auto, auto, auto"
      Padding="10"
      ColumnSpacing="10">
            <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Name}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
           FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Label Text="Powerlevel:"
           Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="{TemplateBinding PowerLevel}"
           Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Label Text="Points:"
           Grid.Column="3"/>
            <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Points}"
           Grid.Column="4"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentView.ControlTemplate>
```

with the code behind

```
public partial class PlayerStubContentView : ContentView
```

{
public string Name
{
get => GetValue(NameProperty) as string;
set => SetValue(NameProperty, value);
}

```
public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(PlayerStubContentView));

public string PowerLevel
{
    get => GetValue(NameProperty) as string;
    set => SetValue(NameProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty PowerLevelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(PlayerStubContentView));

public string Points
{
    get => GetValue(NameProperty) as string;
    set => SetValue(NameProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty PointsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(PlayerStubContentView));

public PlayerStubContentView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

}

I can add these controls and it's rendering fine etc manualy. but the reason for the binding in the collection view of the parent page is to add them programaticaly.

i'm getting a unhelpful error that i'm not sure where it's trying to point me too. i've googled it a lot but i just don't think i know the right words to find what i'm looking for.

[image: Error Message]

***Edit***
The commands in the page view model

```
[RelayCommand]
async void AddNewPlayer()
{
    var newPlayerModel = new PlayerModel() { Name = NewPlayerName, LastPowerLevel = 5, Points = 0 };

    Players.Add(new PlayerStubContentView() { Name = newPlayerModel.Name});
    await _playerService.SavePlayer(newPlayerModel);
    NewPlayerName = string.Empty;
}

[RelayCommand]
async void Delete(string s)
{
    // TODO Figure this out with the new view model approach for the custom component
    //if (Players.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(s))
    //{
    //    var playerToDelete = Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == s);
    //    Players.Remove(playerToDelete);
    //    await _playerService.DeletePlayer(playerToDelete);
    //}
}

[RelayCommand]
async Task Tap(string s)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(PlayerDetailPage)}?PlayerName={s}");
}
```

Comment: the problem is in how your Commands are defined, which you haven't shown the code for.

Comment: please [edit] your question to add new code, don't just stuff it in a comment where it's unreadable

Comment: updated with the code for the commands that are in the code behind. originaly it was a collection of strings and it all worked fine with the commands etc loading and saving to a json file etc. it's only now i've updated the collection to try and use a custom control that i've hit this problem.

Comment: both commands take string arguments, but your `CommandParameters` are bound to `PlayerStubContentView`

Comment: ah. interesting i forgot about them. 2 mins lets see if that cracks it

Comment: all that aside, why aren't you putting `PlayerStubContentView` in the template and binding it to the properties of `PlayerModel`?  Explicitly putting a `View` in your `ViewModel` goes against MVVM

Comment: error's gone thank you. not displaying my bindings but i can play with that at least. thank you again

Comment: i was originally doing it as a view model that i passed in when creating etc but cause i was hitting these problems i tried googling it and i was following a video someone made on how they did it. but now i think i'll go back to the vm pattern consistently. thanks

Comment: @Jason think you need to submit an answer for me to give you the credit too

Comment: the template binding is interesting. this is all pretty new to me i'm a backend web dev mainly. i touched xamarin forms when it first came out a long long time ago but definetly not my area of expertise. part of the problem was not being able to figure out the right words to google. do you have any resources for learning that off the top of your head that you would recomend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both commands take string arguments, but your `CommandParameters` are bound to `PlayerStubContentView`

Comment: Looks great now and i've took your adviced and bind in the template. much cleaner. thank you